# Where $f(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x), ..., f_k(x))$ can you express $f^{-1}(U)$ in terms of $f_i$ where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k, f(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x), ..., f_k(x))$

For an open set $U\in \mathbb{R}^k$, expressed as a countable union $\cup( V_1 \times V_2 ... V_k)$ of open sets $V_i \in \mathbb{R}$

Is there a way to express $f^{-1}(U)$ in terms of $f_i(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

First show that $f^{-1}( V_1 \times \ldots \times V_k) = \cap_i f_i^{-1}(V_i)$. Then, note that the inverse image of a union is the union of the inverse images.

Comment: how do you show $f^{-1}( V_1 \times \ldots \times V_k) = \cap_i f_i^{-1}(V_i)$?

Comment: Think about it for more than 60 seconds.